# Start Execution of Observable after completion of one Observable

Tags: rxjs, angular7

I am new to Angular 7. I have to call one API & wait for completion then start the execution of every HTTP request in my application.

(Note: actual API should start the execution once done the first call. So, In-network tab, calls should go order by )

```
Service.ts :

getService(endpoint) {
     let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'+endpoint;
     return this.http.get(url);
}

public beforeGetService() {
     return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
}

Component.ts :

   this.service.getService('/users').subscribe((data)=>{
       console.log(data);
   });

   this.service.getService('/posts').subscribe((data)=>{
       console.log(data);
   });
```

I would like to handle beforeGetService() invocation in service itself. I have tried like below but calls are working asynchronously  :
Service.ts :

```
getService(endpoint) {
    // Assume it will set some values in header & cookie from beforeGetService()  
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'+endpoint;
    return this.beforeGetService().pipe( 
      concatMap(res => this.http.get(url)
    ) 
}

public beforeGetService() {
     // Assume this service will do some updates on headers & cookie
     return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
}
```

Stackbitz Link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3sxl5

Current execution order of call like :

1. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
2. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
3. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
4. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Expected Behaviour :

1. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
2. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users ( Required to start after completion of 1 st call )
3. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
4. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts ( Required to start after completion of 3 rd call )

Comment: What is your issue and what have you tried ?

Comment: Assume beforePostService() method will set some cookie in header once its completed and I need to set the value in header for next request. That time two calls are going  asynchronously

Comment: Sure, but what have you tried and what is the issue on what you have tried ?

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks your immediate reply 
`
postService(param) {
return this.beforePostService().pipe( 
      concatMap(res => this.http.post(url, param ) )
    )  
}`
I have tried with Rxjs operators like concatMap, faltMap,etc, But All calls are going asynchronously.
`code`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue. And do not post your code as comments, instead provide your code in your question. Consider reading [ask] before posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I hope, now you are clear with question.

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]** reproducing your issue. You can use https://stackblitz.com to do so.

Comment: please take look with stackbitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3sxl5